# Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can not understand asynchority in JavaScript. I think my code should stop at the place I commented on (it goes to if), but it throws a bug:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Sorry for such big code, but I wanted to send everything to make the situation very clear to you.

I think that my method `setTransferHistory(...)` and `sendAuthorizationKey(...)` should be async/await and after doing this code, I want to return status 200.

```
Transaction.findOne({
                where: {
                  id_sender: senderId,
                  id_recipient: recipientId,
                  amount_money: amountMoney,
                  transfer_title: transferTitle,
                  authorization_key: authorizationKey,
                  authorization_status: setAuthorizationStatus(0),
                },
                order: [['date_time', 'DESC']],
              }).then(isAuthorizationKey => {
                if (!isAuthorizationKey) {
                  setTransferHistory(
                    senderId,
                    recipientId,
                    amountMoney,
                    transferTitle,
                    authorizationKey,
                  );
                  sendAuthorizationKey(
                    senderId,
                    recipientId,
                    amountMoney,
                    authorizationKey,
                  );
                  return res.status(200).json({ success: true }); /* it should stop in this place */
                }
```

All of controller:

```
exports.register = (req, res) => {
  function getTodayDate() {
    const today = new Date();
    return today;
  }

  function setAuthorizationStatus(status) {
    const authorizationStatus = status;
    return authorizationStatus;
  }

  async function getSenderEmail(id) {
    try {
      const isUser = await User.findOne({
        where: {
          id,
        },
      });
      return isUser.email;
    } catch (e) {
      /* just ignore */
    }
  }

  async function getRecipientName(id) {
    try {
      const isUser = await User.findOne({
        where: {
          id,
        },
      });
      return `${isUser.name} ${isUser.surname}`;
    } catch (e) {
      /* just ignore */
    }
  }

  function setAuthorizationKey() {
    let authorizationKey = '';
    const possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      authorizationKey += possible.charAt(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length),
      );

    return authorizationKey;
  }

  async function sendAuthorizationKey(
    senderId,
    recipientId,
    amountMoney,
    authorizationKey,
  ) {
    await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: env.nodemailer.host,
      port: env.nodemailer.port,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: env.nodemailer.username,
        pass: env.nodemailer.password,
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: "example"`,
      to: `${await getSenderEmail(senderId)}`,
      subject: 'example',
      text: 'example`,
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  }

  function setTransferHistory(
    senderId,
    recipientId,
    amountMoney,
    transferTitle,
    authorizationKey,
  ) {
    Transaction.create({
      id_sender: senderId,
      id_recipient: recipientId,
      date_time: getTodayDate(),
      amount_money: amountMoney,
      transfer_title: transferTitle,
      authorization_key: authorizationKey,
      authorization_status: setAuthorizationStatus(0),
    });
  }

  Bill.findOne({
    where: {
      account_bill: req.body.account_bill,
    },
  }).then(isAccountBill => {
    if (isAccountBill) {
      const recipientId = isAccountBill.id_owner;
      const authorizationKey = setAuthorizationKey();
      const senderId = req.body.id_sender;
      const amountMoney = req.body.amount_money;
      const transferTitle = req.body.transfer_title;

      if (recipientId !== senderId) {
        Bill.findOne({
          where: {
            id_owner: senderId,
          },
        }).then(isAvailableFunds => {
          if (isAvailableFunds) {
            const senderAvailableFunds = isAvailableFunds.available_funds;

            if (senderAvailableFunds >= amountMoney && amountMoney > 0) {
              Transaction.findOne({
                where: {
                  id_sender: senderId,
                  id_recipient: recipientId,
                  amount_money: amountMoney,
                  transfer_title: transferTitle,
                  authorization_key: authorizationKey,
                  authorization_status: setAuthorizationStatus(0),
                },
                order: [['date_time', 'DESC']],
              }).then(isAuthorizationKey => {
                if (!isAuthorizationKey) {
                  setTransferHistory(
                    senderId,
                    recipientId,
                    amountMoney,
                    transferTitle,
                    authorizationKey,
                  );
                  sendAuthorizationKey(
                    senderId,
                    recipientId,
                    amountMoney,
                    authorizationKey,
                  );
                  return res.status(200).json({ success: true }); /* it should stop in this place */
                }
                return res.status(400).json({
                  error: 'Authorization key has been sent',
                  success: false,
                });
              });
            }
            return res.status(400).json({
              error: 'Sender does not have enough money',
              success: false,
            });
          }
          return res
            .status(404)
            .json({ error: 'Id sender doesnt exist', success: false });
        });
      }
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ error: 'Attempt payment to myself', success: false });
    }
    return res
      .status(404)
      .json({ error: 'Recipient does not exist', success: false });
  });
};
```

Comment: Async functions return an implicit Promise Object and must be treated as such. Returning some value from an Async function does not make sense: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Please don't include "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" in your posts in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `return` inside a Promise callback won't return from the calling code as well. Here's your code in a simplified example

```
if (someCondition) {
  doSomethingAsync().then(() =>
    ...
    return res.status(200).json(...);
  });
}
return res.status(400).json(...);
```

Now given `doSomethingAsync` is asynchronous, you are passing a callback function (`then`) in order to be notified when the I/O bound process has finished. However, whilst this call is underway, the current code will still run to completion so will unintentially call `return res.status(400).json(...)`, hich means, by the time the callback fires for the I/O bound operation you have already ended the request and therefore receive the appropriate error.

To fix this, you need to wait on your asynchronous code to finish *before* you continue, that's exactly what `async` / `await` was designed for

```
if (someCondition) {
  await doSomethingAsync();
  return res.status(200).json(...);
}
return res.status(400).json(...);
```

*Note - you do have a few scenarios in your code where you call `async` functions but don't `await` them e.g. `sendAuthorizationKey`, not sure if that's deliberate but does mean that code more than likely won't complete before the remaining code executes*

Comment: I still do not know how to improve it in my code. :/ @James

Comment: @ReactRouter4 what part are you struggling with?